# react error. Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (11:6)

Tags: javascript

Can you tell whats wrong.
its giving error on currentTodo: ""

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){

    super();
    this.state = {
      todos:[]
      currentTodo: ""
    };


  }
```

Comment: In a javascript object, properties are separated by a comma. You missed a comma after `todos: []`

Comment: hmm, wonder where's walle?

Comment: thanks everyone who corrected me. It was headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a comma.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){

    super();
    this.state = {
      todos:[], // <<<< NOTICE THE COMMA
      currentTodo: ""
    };


  }
```

Comment: Would love to know why this was downvoted? Did i do something wrong here?

Comment: Simple typographical questions should not be answered. Instead do close vote selecting typo...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal And where exactly does it say that?

Comment: This is the reason there's close vote for typo questions.

Comment: @Walle please accept the answer if it helped. click the white check mark near my answer. thanks :)

Comment: is it likely that pointing out how objects should be written in javascript will help other javascript programmers? not really, that comma is what you would learn in the first 10 minutes of learning javascript - clearly a typo and clearly nobody will benefit from this question and answer

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I believe only the question should be down-voted then

Comment: @JaromandaX then the question should be downvoted, not the answer. I'm doing absolutely nothing wrong by pointing out OP's mistake. But I still get downvoted to ashes? And how exactly am i supposed to know that there's close vote for typo questions given that i have only 68 rep and have never close voted a question?

Comment: dunno @YangK - but guess what? *you know now* :p

Comment: @JaromandaX i understand mate. no problem. i'm just getting to know this place and have some things to learn. If whoever had downvoted had just let me know  instead of down voting, that would have been better. No problems tho. Thanks for telling me. :)

Comment: some may see that answering a typographical question will lead to more people posting simple questions like this that can easily be fixed by a) learning the language basics, and/or b) actually following the instructions given in the error message they receive!!

Comment: @JaromandaX yup got it. never knew that. i guess i was thinking SO is more for helping just the OP, but now I understand that the question must be of some use to other users as well in the future. Thanks!

Comment: you're not alone - everyone's probably guilty of answering such a question - and everyon'e probably got *negs* for it - meh - it's like "Whose Line Is It Anyway" - the points don't matter (if they do, you'll have a horrible time here)